# How to uninstall previously installed OpenCV in Windows 7, 64-bit

Tags: windows, opencv, windows-7, windows-7-x64

I wish to uninstall previously installed OpenCV 2.4.3 version and install the 2.4.7 OR 2.4.8 version. My question is how to remove the previous installation completely? I am working on Windows 7, 64-bit. 
Also I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on my system, if that is of any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No need to uninstall. Just rebuild the libraries and put them in the same location as before and you are good to go.

Comment: @scap3y you mean simply install the new version? I did see a video tutorial where they build libraries and all while installing opencv...

Comment: @scap3y would it just overwrite previous files?

Answer (score 3):

you can just delete the folder with the 2.4.3 installation.

you also probably had the 2.4.3 libs in the PATH env variable, you will have to change those to the new 2.4.9 install locations. (but no fear, the dlls are versioned, so you even can have both there)